# Looking for Tool to calculate oringal files from a diff3 merged-file

Tags: command-line, diff, merge

i have a question about merged files produced by diff3.

Im currently working with a java service, that is using diff3 internally to calculate the differences between 3 files. As a result i receive a merged file (basically diff3 -m file1 file2 file3) containing conflicting and non conflicting lines.

For instance:

```
1
<<<<<<< Mine
||||||| Original
2
3
=======
2
>>>>>>> Other
4
5
<<<<<<< Mine
2
3
||||||| Original
=======
3
>>>>>>> Other
6
```

What i want to do now is basically recalculate the original contents of file1, file2 and file3, since i don't have access to those files.

Is there any way to achieve this? For instance with diff3 itself?

Thanks for your help in advance guys. If my elaborations are not comprehensive enough, just tell me.

Kind regards
Thomas